# Why have a router upstream of your firewall

Tags: cisco, router, firewall

I have been coming across a lot of network topologies that look like this:
ISP

!

Router

!

Firewall

!

Inside network

!

And I don't see the purpose of the router in this situation. You can do NAT on the firewall. You can do DHCP on the firewall, you can port forward on the firewall, etc...
Is the only reason to have the router there, to route? Because if you are in a small business situation, you don't need to do that because you'll only have the one network most likely.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my opinions:

1. ISP --- Router (yours) --- Firewall --- Inside network

   I often see this kind of setup in large networks who have their own public IP block and AS number. The main purposes could be:

   - To handle the routing part between your network and ISP. In this case, it is more likely that you will run BGP and receive the full Internet prefixes. Then, you are able to manpulate those prefixes in the way you would like. There is no sense to place a router here and simply put a default route pointing to ISP's IP address.
   - To have more control over your own public IP block and keep it unchanged regardless of ISP. In most cases, the public IP range used for the connection between your router and ISP is managed by ISP, this range will be gone when you change your ISP. A part of your own public IP block would be used for the connection between your router and firewall, and this stay unchanged when you change your ISP from one to another. This is a huge benefit, especially when you have hundreds of VPN tunnels (to branch offices) terminated on your firewall.
   - To attach other parts of your network (not inside network) to this router with configuration on its interfaces or subinterfaces. Those setups may have direct exposure to the Internet if neccessary.
   - To run features barely supported on a router.
2. ISP --- Firewall --- Inside network

   I often see this in networks at SMBs, and mostly you do not own a public IP range but your ISP does.

Answer (score 4):

There can be several reasons for this.

- Why burden your firewall with running services other than its primary
  function? You will get less throughput on the firewall, and that may
  be important.
- Not all businesses use NAT, or they NAT farther inside the business because the business owns a block of public addresses that are exposed at the network edge.
- Running a routing protocol with an ISP may be better done with a
  dedicated router. (Again, not burdening the firewall with services not related to its primary function.)
- Etc.

I would also suggest that businesses probably (or should) use a separate DHCP server.

There may also be more to the network topology than you may see. Without specifics, we really can't tell you why any particular implementation was done that way.

Comment: Additionally: because the ISP provided the router and you don't get to touch it. That's pretty much how it goes in enterprise/business circles.

Comment: Still another reason, although less common now, is that the ISP handoff is a WAN technology that the firewall doesn’t support.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall is more likely is security devices . But router is more operational for routing traffic . Some of the ISPs runs border gateway protocol (BGP).So router can run BGP more efficiently  for establishing connectivity with ISP .

By deploying firewall behind router additional controlling of inbound and outbound traffic can be done on edge router device  by allowing and restricting public IPs with ACL Configurations .it adds additional security to organisation network setup.